# VB reflection in for each loop

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I'm attempting to use an unknown type in a for each loop as per the following code:

```
private sub ReflectThis(ByVal rawData As Object())
  Dim dataType As Type = rawData(0).GetType()
  Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = dataType.getProperties()
  For Each item As dataType In rawData ''//AAAA
    For Each property As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo properties
      ''//reflected code use here
```

The issue that I get is on the line marked AAAA. It complains that 'dataType' is not declared, which I take to mean it does not exist as a proper class.

The intent is to call a web service elsewhere, and regardless of which web service I call, use reflection to add the resulting data struct object's information to a database.

What, if any, are the restrictions on doing something like

```
Dim myObject As variableInstanceOfTypeObjectHere
```

or am I making a more fundamental error? If I'm right, what are the workarounds, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a variable "As" a type, that means you know the type at *compile* time. That lets the compiler check what you're doing with it. In this case, you *don't* know the type at compile time - you're getting it at execution time. All you know is that each item is an object - so either don't specify the type (as suggested by Joel) or specify it as Object:

```
For Each item As Object In rawData ''//AAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't specify the type:

```
For Each item in rawData
```